# Why doesn't execlp allow me to use a pipe?

Tags: c, unix, pipe, exec

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
    execlp("ls" , "ls", "-l", "|" , "sort", NULL);    
}
```

What's going wrong? Please help.

If I write this: `execlp("ls" , "ls", "-l", NULL);` then the result displays on screen and if I try this `execlp("ls" , "ls", "-l", "|" , "sort", NULL);` screen displays error message *cannot access*.

Why? Does anyone have any idea? Why doesn't it allow me to use pipe (`|`) when I execute the command `execlp`?

Comment: because sort is a different program.

Comment: @purpletech What do you mean?Can you explain briefly?

Comment: "ls" and "sort" are two programs. the first argument of execlp can deal with only one program. basically it overlays the memory with this new program that you mention in the first argument and passes the parameters that you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write the following command in a shell

```
ls -l | sort
```

two programs are executed: `ls` and `sort`.

The pipe character (`|`) means that the output of the first should be redirected to the standard input of the second. This pipe is interpreted by your shell. It is not a parameter of your command.

[`execlp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) takes the name of your program and its parameters as arguments.

So when you write

```
execlp("ls" , "ls", "-l", "|" , "sort", NULL);
```

it doesn't make any sense since `|` and `sort` are not parameters of `ls`.

What you want is do what the shell does for you:

1. declare a [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe)
2. make a fork where you redirect stdout to your pipe (with [dup](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup)) and execute `ls`:

   ```
   execlp("ls" , "ls", "-l", NULL);
   ```
3. make a fork where you redirect your pipe to stdin and execute `sort`:

   ```
   execlp("sort" , "sort", NULL);
   ```
4. close your pipe, wait, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Piping is a shell construct. `execlp()` isn't subject to shell parsing; it passes the arguments directly to the named command. To get shell features you need to explicitly start a shell process.

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -l | sort", NULL);
```

In that case it's probably best to specify the absolute path to the shell `/bin/sh`, which means you can use `execl` instead of `execlp`.

Answer (score 2):

Oups, you a making a confusion. `exec...` family functions allow execution of one single program *replacing* the caller one. So your program just execute `ls` command with `"-l"`, `"|"` , `"sort"` as parameters.

Here is what it gives interactively :

```
$ ls "-l" "|" "sort"
ls: sort: No such file or directory
ls: |: No such file or directory
```

On the other end, then you execute normaly `ls -l | sort` in a shell, the `|` **is interpreted by the shell**. And **the shell** :

- starts `ls -l` as a first command
- starts `sort` as a second command
- with output of first command connected to input of second.

You can do that explicitely with the help of `fork`, `pipe` and `execlp`, but you will have to prepare the pipe, and explicitely fork in order to have 2 processes.

Alternatively, you can ask the shell to do the job :

```
execlp("/bin/sh" , "sh", "-c", "ls -l | sort", NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way of doing this. It involves using function `popen`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    FILE* out  = popen("ls -l | sort", "w");

    pclose(out);

    return 0;  
}
```

However it might be not what you were going for as it doesn't use exec.